# print json value from multiple array

Tags: javascript, json

Please help me. I need to get

```
"long_name" : "Coimbatore", 
"long_name" : "Tamil Nadu", 
"long_name" : "India",
```

from json array using JavaScript. Otherwise, please tell me how to get place details using javascript geolocation.

My json array is

```
{
"results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "25",
           "short_name" : "25",
           "types" : [ "premise" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "New Siddhapudur",
           "short_name" : "New Siddhapudur",
           "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "short_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "short_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Tamil Nadu",
           "short_name" : "TN",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "India",
           "short_name" : "IN",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "641044",
           "short_name" : "641044",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "25, New Siddhapudur, Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu 641044, India",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 11.018246,
           "lng" : 76.97244200000002
        },
        "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 11.0195949802915,
              "lng" : 76.97379098029153
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 11.0168970197085,
              "lng" : 76.97109301970852
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "street_address" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "New Siddhapudur",
           "short_name" : "New Siddhapudur",
           "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "short_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "short_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Tamil Nadu",
           "short_name" : "TN",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "India",
           "short_name" : "IN",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "New Siddhapudur, Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu, India",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 11.026501,
              "lng" : 76.983266
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 11.0161269,
              "lng" : 76.96872499999999
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 11.0211533,
           "lng" : 76.9743873
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 11.026501,
              "lng" : 76.983266
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 11.0161269,
              "lng" : 76.96872499999999
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "641044",
           "short_name" : "641044",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "short_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "short_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Tamil Nadu",
           "short_name" : "TN",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "India",
           "short_name" : "IN",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu 641044, India",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 11.0264772,
              "lng" : 76.99028059999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 11.0101754,
              "lng" : 76.9676549
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 11.0174388,
           "lng" : 76.9844677
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 11.0264772,
              "lng" : 76.99028059999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 11.0101754,
              "lng" : 76.9676549
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "short_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "short_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Tamil Nadu",
           "short_name" : "TN",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "India",
           "short_name" : "IN",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu, India",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 11.1929685,
              "lng" : 77.113359
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 10.8914259,
              "lng" : 76.8596541
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 11.0168445,
           "lng" : 76.95583209999999
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 11.1929685,
              "lng" : 77.113359
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 10.8914259,
              "lng" : 76.8596541
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "short_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Tamil Nadu",
           "short_name" : "TN",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "India",
           "short_name" : "IN",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu, India",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 11.4057969,
              "lng" : 77.1766741
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 10.21881,
              "lng" : 76.656036
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 10.9675289,
           "lng" : 76.91820969999999
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 11.4057969,
              "lng" : 77.1766741
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 10.21881,
              "lng" : 76.656036
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Tamil Nadu",
           "short_name" : "TN",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "India",
           "short_name" : "IN",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Tamil Nadu, India",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 13.496666,
              "lng" : 80.3464511
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 8.077270199999999,
              "lng" : 76.23055409999999
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 11.1271225,
           "lng" : 78.6568942
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 13.496666,
              "lng" : 80.3464511
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 8.077270199999999,
              "lng" : 76.23055409999999
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "India",
           "short_name" : "IN",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "India",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 35.5044752,
              "lng" : 97.395555
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 6.7535159,
              "lng" : 68.162386
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 20.593684,
           "lng" : 78.96288
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 35.5044752,
              "lng" : 97.395555
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 6.7535159,
              "lng" : 68.16288519999999
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
  }
],
"status" : "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to get at the list of longnames:

First, get at the list of address_components:

```
var list = obj.results[0].address_components;
```

Create an array of longnames using `map`:

```
var longnames = list.map(function (el) {
  return el.long_name;
});
```

You can then use normal element access to get the name you need.

```
longnames[1] // "New Siddhapudur"
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ST3w7/)

Answer (score 0):

Folks,

I have write following code that may hlep you, result will be in newjson and you have keep in your json in obj

```
var newjson={};
filters=obj.results;for (i in filters){
    //console.log(i);
    for (key in filters[i]){
//        console.log( key + ": " + filters[i][key].length);
         for (var n=0; n<filters[i][key].length;n++){
            if(filters[i][key][n].long_name!=undefined)
            {
            newjson[filters[i][key][n].long_name]=filters[i][key][n].long_name;
            console.log( filters[i][key][n].long_name + ": " + filters[i][key][n].long_name);
            }

         }   
    }
}
```